# Cloudwatch near real time metrics & EC2 sends metric 1 minute periods

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-cloudwatch.html

Based on the above article and the FAQ, is there another article which can I help me better understand the near real time metrics and EC2 sending metric to Cloudwatch in 1-minute periods? 
The FAQ did state near real time for events and log, "*CloudWatch Events is a near real time stream*" and "*With CloudWatch Logs, you can monitor your logs, in near real time*".

Is it, EC2 will send metrics in 1-minute interval to Cloudwatch. Metric which trigger an alarm will be sent to cloudwatch in near real time, not wait for the 1-minute interval.
  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

AWS have three levels of monitoring frequency

- "standard" the free tier 5 minute metrics
- "detailed" the pay for version, 1 minute metrics
- "high resolution" anything under 1 minute

You specifically asked about alarms.  Under high resolution, alarms can be configured for as fast as 10 seconds.

See https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/07/amazon-cloudwatch-introduces-high-resolution-custom-metrics-and-alarms/ for an overview

The normal limit for putMetric adding data is 3 per second see
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch_limits.html

Also you mentioned EC2 specific, default metrics such as CPU and disk.
High resolution metrics are always custom metrics.  AWS metrics are not high resolution

> Metrics produced by AWS services are standard resolution by default. When you publish a custom metric, you can define it as either standard resolution or high resolution. When you publish a high-resolution metric, CloudWatch stores it with a resolution of 1 second, and you can read and retrieve it with a period of 1 second, 5 seconds, 10 seconds, 30 seconds, or any multiple of 60 seconds.

(see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html)

Comment: Thanks Vorsprung! I did not know AWS released high resolution in Jul.

Comment: I will spend some time reading them up. The main point which puzzle me was "near real-time" and 1 minute. As John Hanley pointed out "Every minute means near real time for AWS services".. before the high resolution release.  Thanks both of you.

Comment: So, only the default is free, the others are pay per use?

Comment: @KumarAnkit this answer is over a year old, you should look at the official AWS docs.  It used to be the case that 5m resolution on ec2 was free and 1m was chargeable.

Answer (score 0):

CloudWatch Events sends metrics to Amazon CloudWatch every minute.

This article from Amazon will help you with more details:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cwe-metricscollected.html

Comment: Thanks John for your quick response! Do you mean this list are the events which CloudWatch Events will sends every minutes, and all other events will be in near-real time? Eg: EC2 instances change state to running is in near-real time, include CPU, disk.. metrics?

Comment: Every minute means near real time for AWS services.

Comment: That's one of possibility I thought of, but I can't seem to find supporting text in AWS to confirm it. With Vorsprung provided first AWS link; extracted "enabling you to monitor custom applications and infrastructure in near real-time, down to per-second resolution." .. I think you are right.

Comment: Amazon is constantly improving / changing their services. I periodically read the FAQs and monitor the AWS Blog to stay on top of changes. For my job this takes an hour every day. StackOverflow is a good source of questions to monitor what people are actually doing / having problems with.

Comment: Please don’t mistook that I’m trying to poking fun of you with that example.. I just want to point out the wording used which imply this Jul 2017 release, AWS have updated the near real time for custom metric timing to 1sec… BTW, I read AWS update release notes few times and then I stop..  I need to learn the basic first. I've posted question here before;  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035055/aws-small-setup-secured-public-access-idea-do-away-with-nat-gateway , but I should focus on the SAA exam first. Thanks.